# Meaning and clarification of the notation $\mathbf E:\mathbb R^3\rightarrow \mathbb C^3$

Tags: complex-analysis, multivariable-calculus, complex-numbers, notation, vectors

I use $\mathbf{r}=(x,y,z)$ in the following.

*Question 1:*

Does $\mathbf E:\mathbb R^3\rightarrow \mathbb C^3$ mean I have
$$
\mathbf E(\mathbf{r})=\big(E_{x}(\mathbf{r}),E_{y}(\mathbf{r}),E_{z}
(\mathbf{r})\big) \tag 1
$$
where the components are
\begin{align}
E_x:\mathbb{R}^3\rightarrow\mathbb{C},\quad \text{i.e.} \quad E_{x}(\mathbf{r})&=u_x(\mathbf{r})+iv_x(\mathbf{r})\\
E_y:\mathbb{R}^3\rightarrow\mathbb{C},\quad \text{i.e.} \quad
E_{y}(\mathbf{r})&=u_y(\mathbf{r})+iv_y(\mathbf{r})\\
E_z:\mathbb{R}^3\rightarrow\mathbb{C},\quad \text{i.e.} \quad
E_{z}(\mathbf{r})&=u_z(\mathbf{r})+iv_z(\mathbf{r})\qquad 
\end{align}
Thus is $(1)$
$$
\mathbf E(\mathbf{r})=
\big(
u_x(\mathbf{r})+iv_x(\mathbf{r}),
u_y(\mathbf{r})+iv_y(\mathbf{r}),
u_z(\mathbf{r})+iv_z(\mathbf{r})
\big) \qquad ?
$$

*Question 2:*

Does this mean I can write the components in polar form, i.e.
\begin{align}
E_{x}(\mathbf{r})&=u_x(\mathbf{r})+iv_x(\mathbf{r})=\sqrt{(u_x(\mathbf{r}))^2+(v_x(\mathbf{r}))^2}\, e^{i\phi_x}=\lvert E_{x}(\mathbf{r})\rvert e^{i\phi_x}\\
E_{y}(\mathbf{r})&=u_y(\mathbf{r})+iv_y(\mathbf{r})=\sqrt{(u_y(\mathbf{r}))^2+(v_y(\mathbf{r}))^2}\, e^{i\phi_y}=\lvert E_{y}(\mathbf{r})\rvert e^{i\phi_y}\\
E_{z}(\mathbf{r})&=u_z(\mathbf{r})+iv_z(\mathbf{r})=\sqrt{(u_z(\mathbf{r}))^2+(v_z(\mathbf{r}))^2}\, e^{i\phi_z}=\lvert E_{z}(\mathbf{r})\rvert e^{i\phi_z}
\end{align}
Thus, the vector field in $(1)$ is
\begin{align}
\mathbf{E}(\mathbf{r})=
\big(\lvert E_{x}(\mathbf{r})\rvert e^{i \phi_x},
\lvert E_{y}(\mathbf{r})\rvert e^{i \phi_y},
\lvert E_{z}(\mathbf{r})\rvert e^{i \phi_z}\big) \qquad ?
\end{align}

Comment: what is $\hat{x}$?

Comment: @tomak The unit vector in $x$-direction. I changed to $\hat e_x$.

Answer (score 0):

Q1: I think that ${\bf E}$ would be called a [*vector field*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vector_field) only if the vectors ${\bf E}({\bf x})$ would be ordinary ${\mathbb R}^3$tangent vectors at their base points ${\bf x}$. This is not the case here.

But you have the *vector bundle* ${\mathbb R}^3\times{\mathbb C}^3$, and your ${\bf E}$ is a *section* of that bundle, i.e., a map
$${\bf E}:\quad{\mathbb R}^3\to{\mathbb R}^3\times{\mathbb C}^3,\qquad {\bf x}\mapsto\bigl({\bf x},{\bf E}({\bf x})\bigr)\ .$$
Q2: Your notation is awful.

Comment: This is a mathematician's perspective gone into hyperdrive. Yes, it's a section of the tangent bundle, but the space is flat and there's no harm on taking the isomorphism back to the reference vector space; in the physics literature, where this question gnomes from, it's perfectly acceptable to call this a vector field. And if you find OP's notation distasteful, then maybe stay away from the physics literature? There's much worse stuff there.